# How to hide intent in android?

Tags: android

I have an application with the google map usage. In my case I'm opening the google map, outside from an activity. I did the following,

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
            .parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&mode=driving"));
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

notificationIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
notificationIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

context.startActivity(notificationIntent);
```

But when I'm opening the map It shows over my application. I need to avoid the showing of map on my application. In other words my app should be the top application. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You want to open Google Maps out of your application but your application schould remain on top and GMaps stay in background? Am I right?

Comment: Yes. that's what i want. :)

Comment: Hmm, what is the use case when someone would want it?

Comment: You cannot do that, whenever you start an intent, it always opens on top of the current activity. If you want to do something in the background, use `Services`.

Comment: @AkashSingh how do you expect a service to solve this?

Comment: `In other words my app should be the top application. Is there a way to do this?` According to the mechanic's of the framework this is not possible! `startActivity()` is supposed to launch another activity on top of calling activity!

Comment: @TimCastelijns I just wanted to say that startActivity() always starts activity on top of the activity. And what is the point of starting a activity if the user does not wants it to be shown. In that case, services would be the best choice which are basically UI-less Activities.

Comment: @AkashSingh he wants to open the google maps app, not some random activity

Comment: @TimCastelijns what is the point of opening an app if he doesn't wants the end user to see it?